# Where does apt store downloaded packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, downloads, location

I know that `apt-get` ( as in `sudo apt-get install vim`) stores downloaded packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. However, when using `apt` (as in `sudo apt install vim`) instead, there are no packages stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Where does `apt` store packages?

Comment: @Ravexina shoot! And I was so proud of my digging. Surprised that I didn't find that one while searching!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intriguing question! I donned my deerstalker, stuffed my pipe and did some digging. The answer is: `apt` does not archive packages.

The story goes back to Friday, 13 Sep 2002, when Daniel Quinlan filed [bug report #160743](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=160743), entitled "apt-get clean should run weekly". The rationale was that *"The apt package cache grows without bound [...] runs the danger of filling up smaller disks, especially on systems run by less experienced Debian adminstrators."*

The [bug was closed 14 years later](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=160743#117), on 2 Jan 2016, with little fanfare. The change isn't even mentioned [in the changelog entry](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=160743#124) for apt 1.2. The commit message reads:

```
commit ee02b5b3949372a178d37cadaa08db0bfd5b991f
Author: Michael Vogt <mvo@ubuntu.com>
Date:   Sat Jan 2 22:08:30 2016 +0100

Add new APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages option

This option controls if downloaded packages should be kept after
a successful install or if they should be deleted. The default
for "apt-get" is that they are kept (just like before).

However the default for "apt" is that they get deleted.

Closes: #160743
```

So there you have it. I suppose that the introduction of the new end-user oriented `apt` command (note that `apt-get` is kept backward-compatible so as not to break scripts), was the perfect occasion for closing this historical issue.

Comment: Under appreciated answer :)